# Aspire ES1-511 Power Cable Causes Shutdown

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, acer-aspire

I have an Aspire ES1-511 laptop on battery and if I plug in the charging cable that came with the laptop it immediately shuts down. This started happening after upgrading to Windows 10.

What could be causing this issue? Where do I begin diagnosing it?

Comment: I upgraded to WIndows 10 this week on  laptops. Now if I use the laptops on battery and plug in the wire the that came with the laptop the computers immediately shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

try to reinstall the power management software.

```
device manager > batteries > (right click) microsoft ACPI- compaliant control method battery > uninstall it
```

after uninstalling it , scan for hardware changes from

```
action > scan for hardware changes
```

it will detect the drivers needed to manage the batteries and install it.

or if this doesn't scan then restart the laptop , it will then scan automatically.

i hope this can solve the problem.

***[do on your own risk]***